# Segment violation to the run a generator words

Tags: c, function

This problem occurs when compiling a example provided by a user, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826746/trying-to-generate-9-digit-numbers-with-each-unique-digits/%22this%22) thread, really I do not understand because the error occurs here the code that I used to call the function

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *construct_word(char *const str, size_t len, size_t seed)
{
    char letter[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                        'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                        's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
                      };
    size_t n = 26;

    if (str == NULL || len < 1)
        return NULL;

    while (len > 1 && n > 0)
    {
        const size_t i = seed % n;
        seed /= n;
        str[len++] = letter[i];
        letter[i] = letter[--n];
    }
    str[len] = '\0';

    return str;
}

int main (void)
{
    char buffer[30];
    printf("%s\n", construct_word(buffer, 26, 15));

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone know I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest putting a specific error message in the body of the question.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: You start with str[len++] e.g. str[26] and increment it 26 times more. E.g. You write into str from char 26 to char 52 and your buffer size is 30.

Comment: You should really learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Yes, and so IMMEDIATELY OBVIOUS if run under a debugger, or even with a couple printf calls.

Comment: @Martin James what are the correct values for len and seed

Comment: This might be not an easy bug to debug for a fresh programmer as it crashes later when returning from `main`.

Comment: Well I spotted the error almost immediately after looking at the code. I have some experience but it does feel like you didn't try to understand the code. Not sure SO is the right format for these "find my blunder" questions: what help is us telling you the solution? How is this question useful to others?

Comment: @fukanchik: That will depend on your implementation and environment.

Comment: @Veltas which the problem

Comment: My most prudent advice: *learn to use a debugger*, e.g. gdb if you're using gcc or on a UNIX-style, valgrind is good if you're on Linux. *Stop coming here for these simple problems*, I can be sympathetic that it will take us like 3 seconds to spot the error and you may take many minutes, but you'll learn better if you build a solid notion of the way C works yourself, not just getting strangers to debug everything.

Comment: @Tony: "which the problem" What does that mean?

Comment: gdb is a godsend and would have revealed this issue to you immediately.

Comment: @Veltas maybe a translator error, I'm sorry

Comment: @Tony: Consider finding a *stackoverflow* for your native language. Out of interest, what is your language?

Comment: I do not understand this code should work fine The bug is in that I'm passing incorrect parameters

Comment: @Tony: Read Purag's answer. I think you are wrong and the code has a bug.

Comment: @Veltas el español es mi idioma nativo existe algún sitio de stackoverflow en ese idioma

Comment: @Veltas in this case because no one realized in another thread

Comment: @Tony: Maybe check out [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You pass 26 for `len` when calling the function in `main` and start filling in the buffer at that index. Your buffer has size 30, so after 3 iterations you're accessing and assigning into unallocated space, which causes the segmentation fault.

You probably want another variable, initialized to 0, to use as your index for assigning into the buffer. Loop as long as that variable is `< len`.

```
int bufIndex = 0;
while (bufIndex < len && n > 0)
{
    const size_t i = seed % n;
    seed /= n;
    str[bufIndex++] = letter[i];
    letter[i] = letter[--n];
}
```