# VB.net - permutations of a 9 item (balancing spokes of a wheel)

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, permutation

I have a wheel that takes 9 spokes, due to manufacturing tolerances each spoke has a different weight.

I need to arrange the spokes on the wheel so that it has to least out of balance.

the calculate the balance I sum of the vectors (complex system.numerics), i.e

Complex for spoke #1 =  Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(weight#1, 0)

and

Complex for spoke #2 =  Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(weight#2, 2*math.pi/9)

after performing all the calculations I get the resultant and save the complex real,   Complex.real

then I change the order of the spokes and recalculate the complex.real.

I have 2 questions,

1)  How do I calculate the permutations, change the order efficiently ? I want to avoid 9 nested loops for the (362880) 9! permutations ?

2) Is there a short cut to do the iteration ?

I'm not sure of what other permutation applications there are that could be used as a comparison.

My biggest concern is on efficiency, I sketched up the code today and got stuck on the permutation section. I'll post some code later.

Thanks in advance

I created a class of spokes and weights, from this I can test permitations

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885811/3386109) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code based on a classic algorithm developed by Donald Knuth. (He wrote a great series of books, btw.) You can probably change the bytes to integers since you will have only 9! = 362880 permutations. To use, create a list of bytes with the values 0 - 8. (In that order!) This is your first permutation. In a Do loop, call the algorithm with your list until it returns false. Each time the algorithm is called, the list will be rearranged to the next permutation.

```
Public Function NextPermutation(numList As List(Of Byte)) As Boolean
    '   Donald Knuth's algorithm from the "Art of Computer Programming"
    '   1. Find the largest index j such that a[j] < a[j + 1]. If no such index exists, the permutation is the last permutation.
    '   2. Find the largest index l such that a[j] < a[l]. Since j + 1 is such an index, l is well defined and satisfies j < l.
    '   3. Swap a[j] with a[l].
    '   4. Reverse the sequence from a[j + 1] up to and including the final element a[n].
    '   To get all the permutations, one must start with the 'first' one, which is defined as having all items in ascending order, for example 12345.
    Dim largestIndex As Integer = -1
    Dim i, j As Integer
    For i = numList.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
        If numList(i) < numList(i + 1) Then
            largestIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If largestIndex < 0 Then Return False
    Dim largestIndex2 As Integer = -1
    For i = numList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If numList(largestIndex) < numList(i) Then
            largestIndex2 = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim tmp As Byte = numList(largestIndex)
    numList(largestIndex) = numList(largestIndex2)
    numList(largestIndex2) = tmp
    i = largestIndex + 1
    j = numList.Count - 1
    While i < j
        tmp = numList(i)
        numList(i) = numList(j)
        numList(j) = tmp
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    End While

    Return True
End Function
```

You should also precalculate what you can before starting the permutations. For example, save `2*math.pi/9` to a local variable and use the variable. Perhaps you can also avoid repeated calls to Complex.FromPolarCoordinates, but I didn't dive into the details of your algorithm so I'm not sure if that can be down.

Here's a quick example on how to use the function:

```
    Dim spokes As New List(Of Byte)
    For i As Byte = 0 To 8
        spokes.Add(i)
    Next

    Do
        'Do you balance calculation here.


    Loop While NextPermutation(Spokes)
```

Comment: I suspect that with only 9 spokes that this brute-force method will be sufficiently fast. If you ever need to go beyond 9 spokes, you might want to look into a more efficient optimization such as a branch & bound algorithm.