# Lexicographic order permutation

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I am trying to work on getting a program to print out numbers from 1-4 in lexicographic order. I am only able to permute the array of ints.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 4

void swap(int array[], int i, int j);
void permute(int array[], int low, int len);

int main() {
  int array[LEN], i;

  for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    array[i] = i + 1;

  permute(array, 0, LEN);
}


void permute(int array[], int low, int len) {
  int i;

  if (low >= len - 1 ) {
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
  else {
    for (i = low; i < len; i++) {
      swap(array, low, i);
      permute(array, low+1 , len );
      swap(array, low, i);
    }
  }
}


void swap(int array[], int i, int j) {
  int temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}
```

I have used recursion within the program and swap methods to swap numbers. An explanation of how to approach this or an example would be great.

Example would be:

This is my output

```
1234 
1243 
1324 
1342 
1432
....
```

This is what my output should be

```
1234 
1243 
1324 
1342 
1423
....
```

Notice how the last number is different than my output.

Comment: The description of the problem is unclear. Do you have some examples?

Comment: @EugeneSh. edited the post with example.

Comment: You might find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31830671) to a very similar question interesting; `permutation()` function generates the `index`'th permutation of the contents of the `digits` array to a separate `buffer` (in lexicographic order if `digits` are in lexicographic order). On the other hand, [user3386109's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31885811) shows `nextPermutation()`, which applies a permutation to an array (relying on the character codes to provide lexicographic order), similar to your `permute()` function. Check the other answers, too.

Comment: Sort the remaining part of the array each time you enter `permute()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void permute(int *arr, int ind, int n) {
    if (ind == n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return;
}
    sort(arr + ind, arr + n);
    for (int i = ind; i < n; i++) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[ind]);
        permute(arr, ind + 1, n);
        swap(arr[i], arr[ind]);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this may answer the question, adding an explanation would be useful for people who will read this in the future.