# Combinations from n lists picking one element from each list given an index and the quest for the fastest unranking of combinations

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, combinatorics

I have a ten lists of seven number each and I want to combine each number of each list with the number of any other numbers of the other lists, so that would be 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 x 7 = 282475249 combinations.

Now, if I save them in array with the code below, and the reason is that I need to process a number of them each day, I would need tons of memory, which I do not have:

```
i0 = 0;
for(p1=0;p1<=6;p1++)
{
 for(p2=7;p2<=13;p2++)
 {
  for(p3=14;p3<=20;p3++)
  {
   for(p4=21;p4<=27;p4++)
   {
    for(p5=28;p5<=34;p5++)
    {
     for(p6=35;p6<=41;p6++)
     {
      for(p7=42;p7<=48;p7++)
      {  
       for(p8=49;p8<=55;p8++)
       {
        for(p9=56;p9<=62;p9++)
        {
         for(p10=63;p10<=69;p10++)
         {          

            comb[i0 * 10 + 0] = p1;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 1] = p2;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 2] = p3;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 3] = p4;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 4] = p5;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 5] = p6;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 6] = p7; 
            comb[i0 * 10 + 7] = p8;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 8] = p9;
            comb[i0 * 10 + 9] = p10;

           i0++;
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any way to generate those combinations given an index, so that I can do 1 to 100000 the first day, 100001 to 200000 the second day and so on?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a question about C? Aside: you use magic numbers, but not the *same*. Here `for(p1=0;p1<=6;p1++)` is better as `for(p1=0;p1<7;p1++)` because the nested loop is `for(p2=7;p2<=13;p2++)`. The common magic number is now `7` and not **two** magic numbers `6` and `7`. Suppose you use hard code `8` in different contexts, and you want to adapt the code so one feature has say `10` variants instead of `8`. You will have a difficult maintenance job deciding **which** of the various `8`'s need changing, so a maintainable plan is to put hard coded numbers in a single definition.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, the reason is that is easy for me to remember that are 7 number for list, so 0-6, 7-13, 14-20 and so on, Yes, the question is about C since the above code is in C.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
#define  SIZE  10
#define  BASE  7

void set_combination(char          destination[SIZE],
                     unsigned int  index,
                     const char    source[SIZE][BASE])
{
    int  i = SIZE;

    /* Extract the 'SIZE' digits from 'index', starting
       with the least significant (rightmost) one. */
    while (i-->0) {
        destination[i] = source[i][ index % BASE ];
        index /= BASE;
    }

    /* Make sure destination[] is a string, by adding
       the string-terminating '\0' char. */
    destination[SIZE] = '\0';
}
```

The function interprets index as a SIZE-digit number in base BASE.

The valid range for index is 0 to BASE<sup>SIZE</sup>-1, inclusive. The range wraps around, so index 0 and BASE<sup>SIZE</sup> produce the exact same string in destination. (Assuming `unsigned int` has sufficient range to express that number. In this particular case, with BASE=7 and SIZE=10, 7<sup>10</sup>-1 = 282,475,248, which will fit in an `unsigned int` just fine.)

The leftmost digit will be `source[0][i]`, where `i` is 0 to BASE-1, inclusive. Each digit has their own array of chars. The rightmost digit will be `source[SIZE-1][k]`, where `k` is 0 to BASE-1, inclusive.

---

In a comment, OP asked if this approach can be applied to a situation where the source set is 59 numbers (1 to 59, inclusive), of which three are chosen. (In this case, the number of unique combinations is 59*58*57 = 195054.)

I've shown one approach as `construct_word()` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31830671/1475978). The difference to the above example is that this time, the `source` set is now mutable, and whenever we pick a letter/digit, we remove it from the source set. (Each combination starts with the same `source` set; the changes only occur during the generation of a single combination.) Adapted to OP's particular case, it is something like the following:

```
void  choose_3of59(char          destination[3],
                   unsigned int  index)
{
    char  source[59] = {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
                         11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                         21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
                         31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                         41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
                         51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59 };
    unsigned int  base = 59;
    int           i = 3;

    while (i-->0) {
        /* Remove next 'base'-base digit out of index */
        const unsigned int  k = index % base;
        index /= base;

        /* Add that digit to destination */
        destination[i] = source[k];

        /* Remove this digit from the base set. */
        base--;
        source[k] = source[base];
    }
}
```

with `index` from 0 to 195053 (= 59*58*57 - 1) producing all three-digit combinations, where each digit is unique, and from 1 to 59, inclusive.

Note that while the above does produce all the combinations, the combinations are not in ascending order (that is, `destination[0]*59*59 + destination[1]*58 + destination[2]` is not in ascending order).

---

Some combinations are harder to generate than others.

For example, to generate triplets 1 ≤ n1 < n2 < n3 ≤ 59, with n1, n2, and n3 integers, we can start with the formula that generates the proper index (between `0` and `(57*58*59)/(1*2*3) - 1`, inclusive) for each triplet (n1, n2, n3):

```
index(n1, n2, n3) = ((n1 - 174)*n1 + 10091)*n1 / 6 + (117 - n2)*n2 / 2 + n3 - 1771
```

Next, we can use a binary search to first find the most significant number n1 (at most 6 steps between 1 and 57). Then, when that is found, we can use another binary search to first the middle number n2. Finally, we can use the above equation to solve the least significant number n3:

```
/* Given 0 <= index <= 32508, generate a triplet of integers,
         1 <= num[0] < num[1] < num[2] <= 59
*/
static void set_triplet59(char num[3], unsigned int index)
{
    int  num0, num1, num2;

    /* Make sure 0 <= i <= 32508. */
    index %= 32509;

    /* Note that index 'index' corresponds to triplet 'num0', 'num1', 'num2':
        index(num0, num1, num2) = ( (num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0/6 + (117 - num1)*num1/2 + num2 - 1771

       Also note that
        index(num0, num0+1, num0+2) = index0(num0)
        index(num0, num1, num1+1) = index01(num0, num1) = index0(num0) + index1(num0, num1)
        index(num0, num1, num2) = index0(num0) + index1(num0, num1) + (num2 - num1 - 1)
       where
        index0(num0) = (num0*(num0 - 176) + 10266)*(num0 - 1)/6
        index1(num0, num1) = (num1 + num0 - 118)*(num1 - num0 - 1)/2
        index01(num0, num1) = index0(num0) + index1(num0, num1)
                            = 1/6*num0^3 - 29*num0^2 - 1/2*num1^2 + 10091/6*num0 + 119/2*num1 - 1770
                            = ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0 / 6 - (num1 - 119)*num1/2 - 1770
    */

    /* Use a binary search to find the largest possible num0, where
        index(num0, num0+1, num0+2) <= index.
       The binary search does at most six iterations.
    */
    {
        const int  limit6 = index*6; /* To avoid division by 6 for index0(num0). */
        int        min0   = 1;       /* Inclusive */
        int        max0   = 58;      /* Exclusive */
        while (max0 - min0 > 1) {
            num0 = (min0 + max0) / 2;
            if ((num0*(num0 - 176) + 10266)*(num0 - 1) > limit6)
                max0 = num0;
            else
                min0 = num0;
        }
        num0 = min0;
    }

    /* Use a binary search to find the largest possible num1, where
        index(num0, num1, num1+1) <= index.
       The search does at most six iterations. Note that
        ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0/6 + (117 - num1)*num1/2 + num1 + 1 - 1771 > index
       is can be simplified to
        (117 - num1)*num1/2 + num1 > index + 1770 - ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0/6
       and further to
        (117 - num1)*num1 + 2*num1 > 2*index + 3540 - ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0/3
       and finally to
        (119 - num1)*num1 > 2*index + 3540 - ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0/3
       where the right side is 'limit'.
    */
    {
        const int limit = 2*index + 3540 - ((num0 - 174)*num0 + 10091)*num0 / 3;
        int       min1 = num0 + 1;  /* Inclusive */
        int       max1 = 59;        /* Exclusive */
        while (max1 - min1 > 1) {
            num1 = (min1 + max1) / 2;
            if ((119 - num1)*num1 > limit)
                max1 = num1;
            else
                min1 = num1;
        }
        num1 = min1;
    }

    /* Since we know index, num0, and num1, we can calculate num2 directly. */
    num2 = index + 1771 + num1*(num1 - 117)/2 - num0*(10091 - num0*(174 - num0))/6;

    num[0] = num0;
    num[1] = num1;
    num[2] = num2;
}
```

The above is verified to generate the exact same combinations as

```
index = 0;
for (num[0] = 1; num[0] <= 57; num[0]++)
    for (num[1] = num[0]+1; num[1] <= 58; num[1]++)
        for (num[2] = num[1]+1; num[2] <= 59; num[2]++, index++) {
            /* index, num[0], num[1], num[2] */
        }
```

On an Intel Core i5-7200U (x86-64), `set_triplet59(triplet, index)` takes 145 cycles median, across all valid triplets. As a comparison, `choose_3of59(triplet, index)` takes 115 cycles median, across all combinations. (In other words, you can expect `set_triplet()` to be roughly a quarter to a third slower than `choose_3of59()` on x86-64.)

Comment: thank you very much indeed, great piece of code. How do I port it to use for normal combinations? e.g. choose 7 K items out of 10 N (120 combinations).

Comment: @Mark: Since there are COUNT = BASE**SIZE = 282475248 combinations total, and index ranges from 0 to COUNT-1, inclusive, you can split them into K roughly equal size sets by calculating `C(k) = (COUNT*k)/K`. The `k`'th set is then from `C(k-1)` to `C(k)-1`, inclusive. For example, if `K = 47`, then the 35th (out of 47) set is from `(282475248*34)/47 = 204343796` to `(282475248*35)/47-1 = 210353907` -- which is 6010112 indexes, or about 1/47th of 282475248.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, what if I have something like this: for(p1=1;p1<=59-2;p1++)
{
  for(p2=p1+1;p2<=59-1;p2++)
  {
    for(p3=p2+1;p3<=59;p3++)
    {  }}}   So no more BASE and SIZE but in this case 59 numbers taken 3 at the times. How do I use that indexing code in this case? I previously used the UNRANKCOMB-D ALGORITHM for standard combinations, but your code is much faster, so I want to use it even in that case, besides the original query.

Comment: Seems that the code generate permutations and not combination, 32509 should be the combinations of 59 numbers taken 3 at the time

Comment: @Mark: The code generates an ordered triplet of unique numbers from 1 to 59; I assumed that was what you meant. Apparently not so... Okay, the triple loop `for (p1 = 1; p1 < 58; p1++) for (p2 = p1 + 1; p2 < 59; p2++) for (p3 = p2 + 1; p3 < 60; p3++)` produces triplets `{p1, p2, p3}` where 1 ≤ `p1` < `p2` < `p3` ≤ 59. Is that what you actually wanted? (It is definitely not *"combinations of 59 numbers taken 3 at the time"*.)

Comment: Yes, it is combinations of 59 numbers taken 3 at the time, is the fastest code to generate combinations, no permutations. Your triple loop is wrong, mine is for(p1=1;p1<=57;p1++) { for(p2=p1+1;p2<=58;p2++) { for(p3=p2+1;p3<=59;p3++) { }}} and it will generate combinations I re-tested it just in case I made a mistake. It will generate combinations like: 1 2 3, 1 2 4, 1 2 5, 1 2 6, 1 2 7, 1 2 8 etc etc and not something like 1 3 2 or 3 2 1 etc etc which belongs to permutations.

Comment: set_triplet59 is too slow, I would prefer choose_3of59 but for combinations instead of permutations.