# Getting multiple strings with repeated character

Tags: c, string, algorithm, combinations, backtracking

The problem is getting all possible combinations of that string with permutations.
The solution must be recursive since it uses large values.
For example the number can be

```
888888888999900000000000000000
```

I thought to make a loop and change the position of elements if I put the `n` element on first position and then the `n-1` element on last position I get the same result so this solution generated duplicates.

I don't see any solution for now to be efficient or even to work because changing a position of a character and the changing all other chars position is not a solution at all.
Any hint would be helpful.

I also know the number of each character that is in string from beginning so I don't have to count the number of 8 ,9 and 0.

Comment: `The solution must be recursive since it uses large values.` Why?

Comment: @DeiDei Looping will give repeated values and it's hard to check if it repeated already.I guess

Comment: There are 85 billion possible arrangements of those digits. So regardless of how you do it, it's not going to be fast.

Comment: Just learn about `Next lexicographical permutation` algorithm. Most implementations work with repeated elements.Note that you cannot hope to get all permutations for long strings - their number might be too high.

Comment: @MBo I will check now,I saw some other similar questions like mine but none of the answers were in C and those in C were optimized only for 2/3 chars string

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826746/trying-to-generate-9-digit-numbers-with-each-unique-digits) will generate all 85 billion combinations in about 500 seconds, and yes, it's in C.

Comment: @user3386109 here they don't have unique digits

Comment: The digits don't need to be unique. The digits in the question were unique, but my answer works with duplicate digits. Try my answer with a small test case  so you can verify the results yourself

Comment: @user3386109 your code doesn't work for 0.It will never generate 0000111 and 011111 for example.but I don't know if 0000111 should be considered as as solution.Anyway it's a very good algorithm.PS:My bad it did works with 0,the window output just didnt showed all the results.So sorry

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Good luck with the project!