# What is the optimal way of generating all possible 3X3 magic squares?

Tags: algorithm, magic-square

Magic square: sum of any row, column, or diagonal of length  is always equal to the same number. All 9 numbers are distinct positive integers.

I am doing it this way in JavaScript, but what is the optimal way of generating all of them?

```
function getMagicSquare() {

let myArray = [
    [4, 9, 2],
    [3, 5, 7],
    [8, 1, 5]
];

for (let index1 = 1; index1 < 10; index1++) {
    for (let index2 = 1; index2 < 10; index2++) {
        for (let index3 = 1; index3 < 10; index3++) {
            for (let index4 = 1; index4 < 10; index4++) {
                for (let index5 = 1; index5 < 10; index5++) {
                    for (let index6 = 1; index6 < 10; index6++) {
                        for (let index7 = 1; index7 < 10; index7++) {
                            for (let index8 = 1; index8 < 10; index8++) {
                                for (let index9 = 1; index9 < 10; index9++)
                                // if numbers are not distinct for each loop, I can break the loop and make it a bit faster
                                {
                                    const mySet = new Set();
                                    mySet.add(index1).add(index2).add(index3).add(index4).add(index5).add(index6).add(index7).add(index8).add(index9)
                                    if ((mySet.size === 9))
                                        if (
                                            (index1 + index2 + index3 === index4 + index5 + index6) &&
                                            (index4 + index5 + index6 === index7 + index8 + index9) &&
                                            (index7 + index8 + index9 === index1 + index4 + index7) &&
                                            (index1 + index4 + index7 === index2 + index5 + index8) &&
                                            (index2 + index5 + index8 === index3 + index6 + index9) &&
                                            (index3 + index6 + index9 === index1 + index5 + index9) &&
                                            (index1 + index5 + index9 === index3 + index5 + index7)
                                        ) {
                                            myArray[0][0] = index1;
                                            myArray[0][1] = index2;
                                            myArray[0][2] = index3;
                                            myArray[1][0] = index4;
                                            myArray[1][1] = index5;
                                            myArray[1][2] = index6;
                                            myArray[2][0] = index7;
                                            myArray[2][1] = index8;
                                            myArray[2][2] = index9;

                                            console.log(myArray);

                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Second question: What if I want to generate NxN magic squares?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/ might help.

Comment: If you want to generate an arbitrary sized array, you need to convert this to use some kind of recursive algorithm that nests itself *N* times.

Comment: @nellex thanks for the link. Looks like the link that you mentioned is talking about generating 1 magic square. I am interested in generating all magic squares.

Comment: If your only constraint is "All 9 numbers are distinct positive integers," won't there be an infinite number of magic squares possible?

Comment: [Generate the permutations of the 9 numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826746), and for each permutation distribute the numbers in the square. I'm guessing that javascript has built-in permutation generators that you can use.

Comment: Note that with a 3x3 magic square, there are only `9! = 362880` possibilities, so it's quite easy to try them all. With 4x4, there are `16! = 21 trillion` possibilities so it's quite hard to try them all. And 5x5 is just impossible. So for  bigger squares, you'll need a more clever algorithm.

Comment: Just a heads-up: the bottom-right value of your example matrix should be a 6, not a 5.  Your 5 is already in the middle.

Comment: https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/11/08/how-many-3x3-magic-squares-are-there-sunday-puzzle/

Comment: Relevant mathematics: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X07004682

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty naive implementation using state-space search with basic pruning to generate all possible magic squares of given dimension `n`: https://ideone.com/0aewnJ

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from copy import copy, deepcopy
import time

def magicSum(n):
    return int((n*n * (n*n + 1)) / 6)

def validate(sumDict, n):
    for k, v in sumDict.items():
        if v > magicSum(n):
            return False
    return True

def check(sumDict, n):
    for k, v in sumDict.items():
        if v != magicSum(n):
            return False
    return True

def isValid(m, n):
    rowSum = defaultdict(int)
    colSum = defaultdict(int)
    diagSum = defaultdict(int)

    isLeft = False

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if m[i][j] == 0: isLeft = True
            rowSum[i] += m[i][j]
            colSum[j] += m[i][j]
            if i == j: diagSum[0] += m[i][j]
            if i + j == n - 1: diagSum[n - 1] += m[i][j]

    if isLeft:
        return (validate(rowSum, n) and validate(colSum, n) and validate(diagSum, n))       
    return (check(rowSum, n) and check(colSum, n) and check(diagSum, n))        

def next(cur, m, n):
    possible = []
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(n):
            if m[i][j] == 0:
                nextM = deepcopy(m)
                nextM[i][j] = cur
                if isValid(nextM, n):
                    possible.append(nextM)
    return possible

def printM(m):
    for i in range(len(m)):
            print(m[i])
    print("\n")

def gen(n):
    startM = [[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
    magic = []
    Q = deque([(1, startM)])
    while len(Q):
        state = Q.popleft()
        cur = state[0]
        m = state[1]
        if cur == n * n + 1:
            magic.append(m)
            printM(m)
            continue
        for w in next(cur, m, n):
            Q.append((cur + 1, w))
    return magic

start_time = time.time()
magic = gen(3)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print("Elapsed time: ", elapsed_time)
```

> Output:

```
[6, 1, 8]
[7, 5, 3]
[2, 9, 4]


[8, 1, 6]
[3, 5, 7]
[4, 9, 2]


[6, 7, 2]
[1, 5, 9]
[8, 3, 4]


[8, 3, 4]
[1, 5, 9]
[6, 7, 2]


[2, 7, 6]
[9, 5, 1]
[4, 3, 8]


[4, 3, 8]
[9, 5, 1]
[2, 7, 6]


[2, 9, 4]
[7, 5, 3]
[6, 1, 8]


[4, 9, 2]
[3, 5, 7]
[8, 1, 6]


Elapsed time:  13.479725122451782
```

Though must I say that it performs a bit poorly in terms of run time than expected but I guess it's still good for a start. Will try to optimize it further in a while.

Comment: These are just reflections and rotations.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yep! Just what they should be https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/11/08/how-many-3x3-magic-squares-are-there-sunday-puzzle/

Answer (score 2):

Below is the Javascript implementation for generating all 8 3x3 magic squares.

Algorithm used:

1. Generate one 3x3 magic square ([geeksforgeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/magic-square/)).
2. Derive the remaining magic squares by reflections and rotations ([based on Presh Talwalkar's blog](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2015/11/08/how-many-3x3-magic-squares-are-there-sunday-puzzle/)). There is another method where you can generate the first 4 sets of 3x3 magic square and then derive the remaining 4 by subtracting 10 from each element.

```js
function generateMagic3x3(n) {
  let i, j;
  i = Math.floor(n / 2);
  j = n - 1;
  let baseMatrix = [
    [],
    [],
    []
  ];
  baseMatrix[i][j] = 1;

  for (let k = 2; k <= n * n; k++) {
    i -= 1;
    j += 1;

    if (i < 0 && j === n) {
      i = 0;
      j = n - 2;
    } else if (i < 0) {
      i = n - 1;
    } else if (j === n) {
      j = 0;
    }

    if (typeof baseMatrix[i][j] === 'number') {
      i += 1;
      j -= 2;
    }

    baseMatrix[i][j] = k;
  }
  const baseMatrix2 = reflectDiag(baseMatrix);
  renderMatrix(baseMatrix)
  renderMatrix(reflectRows(baseMatrix));
  renderMatrix(reflectColumns(baseMatrix));
  renderMatrix(reflectColumns(reflectRows(baseMatrix)));
  renderMatrix(baseMatrix2);
  renderMatrix(reflectRows(baseMatrix2));
  renderMatrix(reflectColumns(baseMatrix2));
  renderMatrix(reflectColumns(reflectRows(baseMatrix2)));

};


function reflectColumns(matrix) {
  var newMatrix = matrix.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    newMatrix[row][0] = matrix[row][2];
    newMatrix[row][2] = matrix[row][0];
  }
  return newMatrix;
}

function reflectRows(matrix) {
  var newMatrix = matrix.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });
  for (let column = 0; column < matrix.length; column++) {
    newMatrix[0][column] = matrix[2][column];
    newMatrix[2][column] = matrix[0][column];
  }
  return newMatrix;
}

function reflectDiag(matrix) {
  var newMatrix = matrix.map(function(arr) {
    return arr.slice();
  });
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < matrix.length; column++) {
      if (row !== column) {
        newMatrix[row][column] = matrix[column][row];
      }
    }
  }
  return newMatrix;
}

function renderMatrix(matrix) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  let resBox = document.getElementById('res')
  for (let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    const tr = table.insertRow(row);
    for (let column = 0; column < matrix.length; column++) {
      const cell = tr.insertCell(column);
      cell.innerHTML = matrix[row][column];
    }
  }
  resBox.appendChild(table)
}


generateMagic3x3(3);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='res'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is only one 3×3 magic square (up to rotations and mirroring). The optimal way of generating it is to hardcode it (or the 8 rotations and mirror images of it) in the program.
2. Enumeration of N×N magic squares is an open problem. It is not even known how many 6×6 magic squares exist (it is estimated that the number is about 1.77e19) [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It's very fast but has a significant memory footprint. This implementation would not be good for squares of order 4+ as then you would be attempting to load into memory 16 factorial permutations.

Let me know what you all think.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

a = it.permutations((range(1, 10)))
b = np.fromiter(it.chain(*a), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1,3,3)

ma = np.array([15,15,15])

rs = np.sum(b.reshape(-1,3), axis=1).reshape(-1,3) #row sums
cs = np.sum(b, axis=1) #col sums
ds = np.trace(b, axis1=2, axis2=1) #diag sums
dr = np.trace(np.flip(b,axis=1), axis1=2) #diag flipped sums

i = np.all(rs == ma, axis=1) & np.all(cs == ma, axis=1) & (ds == 15) & (dr == 15)
r = b[i]

print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much optimised but somewhat cleaner and easy to understand approach.

```
bool is_magic(int n, vector<int> vec, int m_sum) {
    vector<vector<int>> values(3, vector<int>(3, -1));

    for(int i=0; i<9; i++) values[i/3][i%3] = vec[i];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int r_sum = 0;
        int c_sum = 0;
        int ld_sum = 0;
        int rd_sum = 0;
        
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            r_sum+=values[i][j];
            c_sum+=values[j][i];
            ld_sum+=values[j][j];
            rd_sum+=values[j][n-1-j];
        }
        if (r_sum!=m_sum) return false;
        if (c_sum!=m_sum) return false;
        if (ld_sum!=m_sum) return false;
        if (rd_sum!=m_sum) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void magicSquare(int n) {
    vector<int> values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int m_sum = accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0)/3;
    
    vector<vector<int> > combs;
    do {
        if(is_magic(n, values, m_sum)) combs.push_back(values);
    }  while(next_permutation(values.begin(), values.end())); 
}

output=>

2 7 6 
9 5 1 
4 3 8 

2 9 4 
7 5 3 
6 1 8 

4 3 8 
9 5 1 
2 7 6 

4 9 2 
3 5 7 
8 1 6 

6 1 8 
7 5 3 
2 9 4 

6 7 2 
1 5 9 
8 3 4 

8 1 6 
3 5 7 
4 9 2 

8 3 4 
1 5 9 
6 7 2 

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.65 seconds
```