# Printing all possible strings with given characters in dictionary order

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sorting

Problem description:

> He handed you a string and asked if you could make as many different words as possible using its characters.
>
> Excited to give it a try, you got to work. It felt a bit like solving a puzzle, and finding new ways to arrange the letters.
> Each arrangement revealed a new and interesting word. You eagerly dove into the task, ready to discover all the different words
> you could create with those given letters.
>
> Input Constraints: `1 <= n <= 8`
>
> Input: The only input line has a string of length `n`. Each character is between "a-z".
>
> Output: First print an integer `k`: the number of strings.
> Then print `k` lines: the strings in alphabetical order.

This is my code and would like to ask how to modify to get the required output in alphabetical order. Time constraint is 1sec.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "quick_sort.h"
#include "swap.h"

void permutations(char array[], short length, short left)
{
    if (left == length)
    {
        //swap(&array[left - 1], &array[i]);
        printf("%s", array);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = left; i <= length; i++)
        {
            int is_duplicate = 0;
            for (int j = left; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (array[j] == array[i])
                {
                    is_duplicate = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!is_duplicate)
            {
                swap(&array[left], &array[i]);
                permutations(array, length, left + 1);
                swap(&array[left], &array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    char input[10] = "";
    fgets(input, 9, stdin);
    short str_len = strlen(input);
    //printf("%hd", str_len);
    quicksort(input, str_len - 1);
    //fputs(input, stdout);
    permutations(input, str_len - 2, 0);
    /*quicksort(input, str_len);*/
}
```

Comment: Remember that [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) *can* include the newline in the buffer. You should probably [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) it. And using the string length minus one is not good enough, because that could lead to other problems (especially if the newline actually *isn't* included).

Comment: The answer to your main question is you should put all the results in an array and sort the array before printing it.

Comment: The permutations can be generated iteratively in alphabetic order [using the code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826746/trying-to-generate-9-digit-numbers-with-each-unique-digits/31885811#31885811).

Comment: Knuth's "Algorithm L" (*Lexicographic permutation generation*) will take care of permuting the initially sorted string contents. You also need to output the number of strings before outputting any strings. You can do that by dividing the factorial of the length by the factorials of the repeat counts for each letter. E.g. for a string of length 6 with letter repeat counts of 2, 1, 3 (e.g. "aabccc"), the number of strings will be 6! / (2! * 1! * 3!) = 720 / (2 * 1 * 6) = 60.

Comment: `lg_2(8)*26=78` bits easily fits into a perfect hash; I assume that was intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on Knuth's "Algorithm L" from "The Art of Computer Programming", Volume 4, Fascicle 2. See Muktal Gupta's blog post [Understanding Algorithm L](http://guptamukul.blogspot.com/2009/12/understanding-algorithm-l_05.html) for a description of how it works.

The program is required to output the number of strings before outputting any strings. The `count_permutations()` function calculates the number of strings that will be output.  If all the characters in the string of length *n* are different, the number is just the factorial of *n*.  For each distinct letter in the string, the number needs to be divided by the factorial of the number of occurrences of that letter. For example, if the string consists of 1 'a', 2 'b's, and 5 'c's for a total length of 8, the number of strings will be 8! / (1! × 2! × 5!) = 40320 / (1 × 2 × 120) = 168.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "quick_sort.h"
//#include "swap.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char x = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = x;
}

int cmpchar(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    char av = *(const char *)a;
    char bv = *(const char *)b;
    return (av > bv) - (av < bv);
}

void quicksort(char *arr, size_t len)
{
    qsort(arr, len, sizeof *arr, cmpchar);
}

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int fac = 1;
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fac *= i;
    }
    return fac;
}

unsigned int count_permutations(const char *a, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int count = factorial(n);
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int run;

    run = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[i - 1])
        {
            count /= factorial(run);
            run = 0;
        }
        run++;
    }
    count /= factorial(run);
    return count;
}

/* Steps L2 to L4 of Knuth's Algorithm L. */
int permute(char *a, int n)
{
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;

    if (n < 1)
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    /* L2. [Find j.] (N.B. reduce indices by 1 for C arrays.) */
    for (j = n - 1; j > 0 && a[j - 1] >= a[j]; j--)
        ;
    if (j == 0)
        return 0;
    /* L3. [Increase a_j.] (N.B. reduce indices by 1 for C arrays.) */
    for (l = n; a[j - 1] >= a[l - 1]; l--)
        ;
    swap(&a[j - 1], &a[l - 1]);
    /* L4. [Reverse a_(j+1) ... a_n.] (N.B. reduce indices by 1 for C arrays.) */
    for (k = j + 1, l = n; k < l; k++, l--)
    {
        swap(&a[k - 1], &a[l - 1]);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char input[10] = "";
    int len;

    if (fgets(input, 10, stdin) && input[0] != '\n')
    {
        len = strlen(input);
        /* Limit length. */
        if (len > 8)
        {
            len = 8;
        }
        /* Remove newline. */
        if (input[len - 1] == '\n')
        {
            len--;
        }
        input[len] = '\0';
        /* Initially sort in ascending order. */
        quicksort(input, len);
        /* Print number of permutations. */
        printf("%u\n", count_permutations(input, len));
        /* Use Knuth's Algorithm L (Lexicographic permutation algorithm). */
        do
        {
            /* L1. [Visit.] */
            puts(input);
        }
        while (permute(input, len)); /* Steps L2. to L4. */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `input[--len] = '\n';` is incorrect if the input is not terminated with a newline. Use `if (input[len - 1] == '\n') input[--len] = '\0';` and use `puts(input)` in the `do`/`while` loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks for the code I will go through the algorithm.